# Anchor tag is not getting clicked when using with Area - ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have toolbar in my project. Suddenly list items are not being clicked on it since I have added `area` in project and moved controllers and views in respective folders.

`Home` and `Category` are not clickable. This is my code in _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - RegistrationApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/BoostwatchTheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/RegistrationApp.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
                
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Customer" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">

                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index">Category</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is `_ViewImports.cshtml` which is there in the both `areas` folder Admin and Category

```
@using RegistrationApp
@using RegistrationApp.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

This is my project structure

[image]

These two `Home` and `Category` options are not getting clicked

[image]

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Just a random guess but have you changed the namespaces to correspond to the new folder structure.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos - Yes I did it..